# php login problem work on localhost and not wotk at the server

Tags: php

Now when I press the login button nothing happens and the username and password are cleared.
the code on my pc "localhost" is working but on the server is not working ... any idea please

this is the login.php page
and i dont think its the problem 
and i check for problem at index file or connection file there no problem 
as i say its work on my pc 
and when i upload it at the server its not work

````
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "index.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "exit.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
   }
   else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}

mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query_rs_setting = "SELECT * FROM settings";
$rs_setting = mysql_query($query_rs_setting, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_setting = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_setting);
$totalRows_rs_setting = mysql_num_rows($rs_setting);
?> ```
````

Comment: Is the server on PHP 7+ - as the `mysql_` api is deprecated.

Comment: no the server is php 5.6 but i think this is the problem ... and cant install php version less than 5.6 ... what do you think  ???